# Add db_index = True to a Django model which already has a lot of data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add indexing to an already existing Django model field by adding `db_index = True`. The corresponding table already has a lot of data in the database. Will adding `db_index = True` to the field automatically index the values after migrating with the new changes?

Comment: It should work. but make a database backup first. You may have to add in your `db_index=models.BooleanField(default=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, yes. This would create an index in you sql table. So whenever you run your `migrations` your table would have added the index.

If you want to try hardcoding it you can in your migration script by adding it in your forward method. It would probably look something like this

```
db.execute("CREATE INDEX my_index on table_name(col_name)", params=[])
```

Comment: The db added the index post migration after adding db_index=True.